# State to std_logic

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I have defined my state as follows:

```
type state_type is (s0, s1, s2, s3);
signal state   : state_type;
```

Now I would like to use this state information to form another signal

```
signal data : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal data_plus_state : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);

....
data_plus_state <= data & state;
```

Does anyone know how I can concert state into a std_logic_vector so that I can concatenate these
two signals?

Many thanks,
Rob

Comment: Belongs on ChipHacker, but no option provided by SO. Bad SO!

Answer (score 2):

Define a subprogram that convert state to std_logic_vector.

That subprogram contains a case statement, something like:

```
case state is
  when s0 => return <std_logic_vector value for s0>;
  when s1 => return <std_logic_vector value for s1>;
  when s2 => return <std_logic_vector value for s2>;
  when s3 => return <std_logic_vector value for s3>;
end case;
```

Answer (score 2):

The subprogram and case answer would work very well. If you wanted something in line you could use this.

```
signal state_slv : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);

state_slv <= "00" when state = s0 else
             "01" when state = s1 else
             "10" when state = s2 else
             "11";

data_plus_state <= data & state_slv;
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to put two (or more) signals into one signal (or port).

The way to go here is not *concatenating* the signals, but rather put them in a record. The advantage is that the semantics (the *meaning*) of each part of the signal is clearly expressed. This way you don't have to encode (and later decode) every data element.

```
type state_type is (s0, s1, s2, s3);
signal state   : state_type;
signal data : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
type data_plus_state_type is record
    data : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    state: state_type;
end record data_plus_state_type;
signal data_plus_state : data_plus_state_type;
```

Then you can put the two signals in a single record signal:

```
data_plus_state <= (data, state);
-- or:
data_plus_state.data <= data;
data_plus_state.state <= state;
```